# QGIS OSM Basemap with English place names?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, basemap

I am pretty new to QGiS and to cartographic software in particular. I wanted to create some maps of some cities in the Arab Gulf and wanted to use an Open Street Maps basemap. However, everything in the region is labelled in Arabic, which I can read but most of my target audience probably not. Is there a way to change the labels into English? Or do you know another good open source basemap for the region that I could/should use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have seen, the default OSM renderer displays map features in the local language of each feature, not in your language. One option is to look for an alternative tile server that suits your needs. @scai notes some alternatives listed at https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Map_internationalization (but be sure to abide by any provider's ToS).

Another option is to render your own tiles. Have a look at the accepted answer on [Setting map language to English in Openstreetmap with LeafletJS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18595192/9794865) as a good starting point.

Comment: You don't necessarily need to render your own tiles. There are various alternative tile servers available, some of them have all-english labels. See https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Map_internationalization for examples.

Comment: Good one @scai; I've updated my answer.